# How to get user's preferred language, that is not supported by application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I'd like to figure out the system's preferred language, I've put at the top in the system's preferences. I was hoping `Locale.preferredLanguages` or `Locale.current` would work, unfortunately it seems to only return those languages that are also supported in the application's bundle.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why I didn't get the preferred language was because I set *Application Language* to English in the options of my Xcode Scheme. If you don't have it on System Language, `Locale.preferredLanguages` or `Locale.current` will always just return the language you specified (of cause).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the Xcode Scheme took hours to find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`Locale.current` is correct and will work, but it may require you to restart the app or your computer if you changed languages recently.

```
print(Locale.current.debugDescription)
```

Outputs my system language `sv_SE (current)` for me on a non-localised project.

Comment: Thanks Oskar, that should work of cause. So does `Locale.preferredLanguages[0]`. The cause of my issue was elsewhere (see my answer)